# adding a new row to a table when adding another row in a different sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel workbook in which I have several tables. On 3 of my sheets, there is some kind of "main" table which differ a bit from one another.

These tables are 2 lines by default (1 header and 1 data row) and extend when I add a new line below the one already existing. In some of the fields are formulas which are using values from the other tables. However, if for example, I insert a new value in a field below the final row, thus adding another row to the table, I want the tables in the other sheets to also add another row (and execute the formulas that are in the new row)

This is the sheet in which I have "Soorten Vezels" with their corresponding "max demping" and "soorten connectoren" with their corresponding "max demping":
[image]

This is the "maximale demping" file:
[image]

This is the measurement form, in this form, the user should not have to enter anything, except for the 2 dropdown menu's "type kabel" and "type connector":
[image]

What I would like is that when the user for example, inputs the length ("lengte") in the "maximale demping" file, a new row gets added (the fields "kabelnr", "van" and "naar" will be filled in automatically from the "gegevens" file)

But I would also like the workbook to add a new line in the measurement form, automatically fills in the "kabelnr", "van" and "naar" fields. So that I only have to choose the "type kabel" and "type connector" from the dropdown menu.

How do I do this (with VBA)?

Comment: @yvette currently none, I do have some vb.net experience.. but I'm not sure how I should do this

Comment: @Yvette well if you could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I like the MSDN when I am looking for answers to VBA and vb.net. I have found it to be thorough and comprehensive. The more I learn, the more I understand what they are teaching on this site.

This is a good tutorial to get started. Follow the links from this page.

**Getting Started with VBA in Excel 2010**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx

**Also remember to search Stack Overflow as you progress, there are an amazing number of questions covering specifics you may require when you start, or ask more questions.**

If you require further assistance you can look at the links below.

This link is helpful. But I would navigate through the links below to get a broader view and to find an explanation that works for you.

**Insert Row in Tables Multiple Sheets Excel 2010**

http://chandoo.org/forums/topic/insert-row-in-tables-multiple-sheets-excel-2010

A forum- this link leads to a question about inserting rows.
MrExcel.com

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/58685-insert-rows-between-different-data-2-a.html

If you persevere, down the page, there is good discussion, with code examples and trouble shooting (you will get a pop up when you go to this link asking to sign up for the newsletter, you can disregard this without a problem)

**Insert Row in Tables Multiple Sheets Excel 2010**

http://chandoo.org/forums/topic/insert-row-in-tables-multiple-sheets-excel-2010

A useful Q&A from Microsoft forum.

**Insert blank rows in excel table with vba**

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-customize/insert-blank-rows-in-excel-table-with-vba/69e369a8-e656-4f68-adcd-c57e37253f12

Please let me know if this helps and ask new questions freely as you go.

Comment: Eventhough this is not the answer to the question, I have marked this as the answer due to the massive amount of useful information!